# onActivityCreated is not called when when app is opened from minimised state

Tags: android

I'm replacing multiple fragments on an activity. using below code

```
FragmentManager fragmentManager = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager();
FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
Fragment fragment = new LessonContentFragment();
fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.flContent, fragment);
fragmentTransaction.commit();
```

Every time when i click on home button of mobile onSaveInstanceState getting executed, but when i opene the app again from minimised state, onActivityCreated is not getting executed. What may be the problem

```
@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
    if (savedInstanceState != null) {
        //Restore the fragment's state here
        int myInt = savedInstanceState.getInt("MyInt");
        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), myInt, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    //Save the fragment's state here
    outState.putInt("MyInt", 1);
}
```

I have below code in my fragment. but when app is not in resume state and onfinish gives error. how to solve this?

```
new CountDownTimer(assmt_time, 1000) { // adjust the milli seconds here
                    public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
                        timer.setText("" + String.format("Time left: " + "%02d:%02d",
                                TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(millisUntilFinished),
                                TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toSeconds(millisUntilFinished) -
                                        TimeUnit.MINUTES.toSeconds(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(millisUntilFinished))));
                        if (millisUntilFinished < 10000) {
                            if (blink_flag != 1) {
                                blink_flag = 1;
                                blink();
                            }
                        }
                        if (millisUntilFinished < assmt_time10per) {
                            if (colour_flag != 1) {
                                colour_flag = 1;
                                timer.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#D50000"));
                            }
                        }
                    }

                    //"%02d:%02d:%02d"
                    public void onFinish() {
                        //timer.setText("done!");
                        of.setForceSubmit(1);
                        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager();
                        FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
                        Fragment fragment = new SubmitFragment();
                        fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.flContent, fragment);
                        fragmentTransaction.commit();
                    }
                }.start();
```

Comment: OnResume() will be executed when you open it(Resume it)  again

Comment: @Developer Does fragments have that method?

Comment: OnCreated() is called only when the Activity is ... created. When you click the home button you do not destroy your activity, you just pause it. So when you re-open it you just trigger onResume(). Take look [here](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/activity-lifecycle.html)

Comment: ofcourse, It has.

Comment: @vincrichaud I'm talking about fragments. Does fragments have onResume etc?

Comment: @Veer My fault I understood wrong. For fragments take a look [here](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html#Lifecycle)

Comment: @Developer yes onResume is getting executed

Comment: @Developer what may be the problem?

Comment: @ vincrichaud I'm talking about fragments. In fragment when i load first time onCreateView,onActivityCreated,onResume are getting executed ,when i minimise the app onSaveInstanceState is also getting executed,but when i open from minimised state directly on resume is called why?

Comment: onActivityCreated() is called when the fragment's activity has been created and this fragment's view hierarchy instantiated. And it is called after onCreateView(). When you are minimizing,both the activity and fragment not destroyed. It will be in paused state. When you open it, It is resumed. The onActivityCreated() is called when fragment is initiated

Comment: @Developer  Then how save the state and restore in fragments, while i replace multiple fragments one after the other

Comment: @Veer [`onSaveInstanceState()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html#onSaveInstanceState(android.os.Bundle)) can be called multiple times but state is not saved.

Comment: @global_warming what? are you serious? then how to save the state?

Comment: @Veer check documentation for `onSaveInstanceState()`

Comment: @Developer I have edited my question please check

Comment: @global_warming I have edited my question please check

Comment: @vincrichaud I have edited my question please check